# How to populate a blank form field with onSubmit

Tags: javascript

New to JavaScript so please forgive my ignorance.

I have a form where when the customer submits the form it checks a specific field and if it's left blank I need it to populate it with a specific code. Any ideas how I can do this?

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="checkout">

<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
 <tr>
  <td align="right" class="normaltext" width="40%">
   <b>Catalog Code:</b>
  </td>
  <td align="left">
   <input type="text" name="cat_code" value="{$valid.cat_code}" size="25" class="formtext" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue &gt;" class="addtocart_btn btnstyle1" />
```

Comment: What Do u want us to answer ?

Comment: I think his question is how he can populate blank fields when the form got submitted

Comment: Why not just handle it on the server side?  What's the reason for doing it with Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use jQuery to do something like this:

```
<form id="checkout" name="checkout" method="post" action="index.php">
    <input id="input1" type="text" value="" />
    <input id="input2" type="text" value="" />
    ...
    <input id="inputn" type="text" value="" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("checkout").submit({
        if ($("#input1").val() == "") {
            $("#input1").val() = "Your desired value for input1";
        } 
        // put more if condition to populate the blank fields as needed
    });
<script>
```

Comment: As Mark comments above, you should do these thing on the server side. The above code is more meaningful if you want to alert the client that he missed some fields and prevent the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `onsubmit` handler to your form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function()
    {
        document.forms.checkout.onsubmit = checkBlankField;
    }
    function checkBlankField()
    {
        var field = document.forms.checkout.cat_code;
        if (!field.value)
        {
            field.value = "some value";
        }
    }
</script>
```